# Why is this MySQL procedure syntax incorrect? Works on test server

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have written several procedures and succesfully implemented them on my webhost's server. However with this procedure i get the  #1064 error. I wrote it in MySQL Workbench and it did not complain one bit. Works fine on my local machine.

```
USE mydb
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `temp`(
  IN p_page int(11),
  IN p_approved varchar(3))
  BEGIN
    DECLARE v_postsPerPage tinyint;
    DECLARE v_totalPostCount int(11);
    DECLARE v_listFrom int(11);

    SELECT posts_per_page INTO v_postsPerPage FROM diskus_settings;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_totalPostCount FROM diskus_post;

    SET v_listFrom = p_page * v_postsPerPage - v_postsPerPage;

    SELECT p.post_id, p.user_id, u.username, get_time_diff(p.date) as date, p.ip, p.text, p.parent_post_id, p.approved AS posts
    FROM diskus_post p, diskus_user u
    WHERE p.user_id = u.user_id
      AND p.approved = p_approved
    ORDER BY p.date DESC LIMIT v_listFrom, v_postsPerPage;
END $$
```

Comment: If you're getting error 1064 (sql syntax error), it should also be giving you a snippet of sql from where the error occured.

Comment: Near 'v_listFrom, v_postsPerPage;
END' at line 20, but I can't see why..

Comment: If you want to write your limit clause dynamically you will have to create it as a string and pass it to prepare. MySQL >= 5.5.6 you can use variables in the LIMIT clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work -

```
USE mydb
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `temp`(IN p_page int(11), IN p_approved varchar(3))
  BEGIN
    DECLARE v_postsPerPage tinyint;
    DECLARE v_totalPostCount int(11);
    DECLARE v_listFrom int(11);

    SELECT posts_per_page INTO v_postsPerPage FROM diskus_settings;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_totalPostCount FROM diskus_post;

    SET v_listFrom = p_page * v_postsPerPage - v_postsPerPage;

    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT p.post_id, p.user_id, u.username, get_time_diff(p.date) as date, p.ip, p.text, p.parent_post_id, p.approved AS posts
        FROM diskus_post p, diskus_user u
        WHERE p.user_id = u.user_id
        AND p.approved = p_approved
        ORDER BY p.date DESC
        LIMIT ', v_listFrom, ', ', v_postsPerPage);

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END $$
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me working code, easier for me to understand. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 2):

> [12.2.9. SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)
>
> > Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using
> >     integer-valued routine parameters or local variables as of MySQL
> >     5.5.6.

[SP does not accept variables in LIMIT clause](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11918)